# Cannot generate core dump file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debugging, gdb, coredump

I've been getting segmentation fault errors on a vulkan renderer I wrote in c++ and the terminal says it has been core dumped, I want to send the core dump file through gdb to debug where the segmentation fault is happening, but I cannot find the core dump file in the project directory nor anywhere else. I noticed that in apport.logs ([the apport.logs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTW0j.png)) it appears as if the core limit is set to 0, so I suppose no core dump file is being generated.
I tried changing the ulimit -c limit in the shell session where I want to generate the core dump, but it does not seem to work. I also tried setting the core dump limit to unlimited on limits.conf, it didn't work too.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to send the core dump file through gdb to debug where the segmentation fault is happening

Note that you *don't need* a `core` dump to debug -- you can debug a live process instead. Just do `gdb --args /path/to/binary args...`. Then use `run` to run the binary, and `where` once GDB stops due to a crash.

If you really want to get a `core`, you can tweak `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`. Use `cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to see where the `core` dumps are currently going (probably a pipe to `apport`).

Use `echo core | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to make `core` appear in the current directory.